# Declare variable in C - Many ways?

Tags: c

I'm discussing with a friend what's the correct way to declare some variables in C, exactly in the for loop.

He has a compiler I can't remember and I have Dev-C++.

He does:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
// ... and it works
```

I do:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
// ... and it works
```

If I do it like he does, Dev-C++ gives me an error. What's the technically correct way to do this? I was taught to do it the way I do but now I'm confused because he does it in  the other way and it works for him D:

Comment: Either of these may be correct. Your friend's way limits the scope of the definition of `i` to the `for` loop which is correct for encapsulation *if* you need it. But it's not supported in all revisions of the C standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declaring the variable in the loop, like your friend does, is supported in C99 and in C++. It is likely that your friend is coming from a C++ background, where such style of declaration is the norm. Declaring the loop variable outside the loop, like you do, is correct in older C, such as C89, which is what your compiler apparently supports.

If you have access to a C99 compiler, which style to choose is mostly a matter of preference. Seasoned C programmers don't mind declaring variables outside loop bodies, but it is considered slightly cleaner to declare them inside because it restricts the scope of the variable to the least possible lexical region. Declaring the variable outside the loop body is, of course, necessary if you plan to use it after the loop is done — for example, to inspect how far the loop has progressed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of which version of C you're using. Ansi C (original, Ritchie & Kernighan) only supports declaration at begin of block while modern C (and any flavour of C++) allows mixing statement and declaration.

```
{ 
   int a;
   printf ("Stuff);
   int b; /* not allowed */
}
```

Comment: Note that the question is not about mixing statements and declarations, but about declaring variables inside the `for` clause. Also, the answer misspells the names of Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: Fixed typo for the authors. inside of a for loop is not considered a block, thus my answer. You're however correct and it ain't precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a value inside of the for-loop header causes an error in any compiler that predates c99. If you compile this with the c99 standard or newer, it will work just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Formally the physical difference between THESE TWO is the performance. put the definition within the brackets after for may have more chances to be as a register-only variables. But on the other hand there are many other factors which can decide the detail of optimization results, with the help of the analizing mechanism of the compiler. So the final result may be no different or even be opposite.
  There is indeed a different for sure: if you define a variable within the brackets after 'for', that variable won't be able to be used at the outside of that for-loop.

Comment: Where the variable is declared will be completely and utterly irrelevant to any optimizing compiler worth its salt.